# How can I cut a string in multiple .csv filenames while keeping the starting strings in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

This is the sample of the .csv files I have in a folder 84 files

```
W17F07mylatest0_077004_20220214_122524_a
W17F07mylatest0_077005_20220214_122530_a
W17F07mylatest0_077006_20220214_122537_a
W17F07mylatest0_077007_20220214_122543_a
```

I would like to remove "_20220214_122524_a" part of each file to get:

```
W17F07mylatest0_077004
W17F07mylatest0_077005
W17F07mylatest0_077006
W17F07mylatest0_077007
```

I tried using

```
movefile('W17F07mylatest0_077005_20220214_122530_a.csv','W17F07mylatest0_077005.csv')
```

or

```
newStr = extractBefore(W17F07mylatest0_077005_20220214_122530_a.csv, "_2022");
name_join = strcat(newStr, ".csv");
```

I could only change for a single file per time, but needs a code to loop for all the files in the folder.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that the underline position is not changing, maybe use this

```
fname='W17F07mylatest0_077004_20220214_122524_a';
fnamesplit=split(fname,'_');
fnamej=strjoin(fnamesplit(1:2),'_');
fnamej =

'W17F07mylatest0_077004'
```

For batch processing:

```
filedir=dir('.\*.csv');
for ifd=1:length(filedir)
    fname=filedir(ifd).name;
    fnamesplit=split(fname,'_');
    fnamej=strjoin(fnamesplit(1:2),'_');
    movefile(filedir(ifd).name,fnamej) 
end
```

I don't have actual files to test these. Please let me know if you get into any errors.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. This would be effective for a single file. Do you know how I can use it for multiple files?

Comment: @Timi Updated my answer. Please let me know if any error shows up.